# How do I add minutes (from a textbox value) to a DateTime

Tags: vb.net

Im currently writing a program which is taken me a long time now as it been over 8 years since i did any programming.

Im currently using a datetimepicker for my time with a custom format.

What i want to do is add minutes to this time from a text box (tbAccTime)

The data is being placed within a datagridview.

This is what i got:

```
Public Class Form1

  Friend myFormat As String = "HH:mm:ss" '"H:mm:ss tt" 'use this for 12 hour time

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    Dim myFormat As String = "HH:mm:ss" '"H:mm:ss tt" 'use this for 12 hour time
    DateTimePicker1.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom
    DateTimePicker1.CustomFormat = myFormat
    DateTimePicker1.ShowUpDown = True

Private Sub bntcalculate_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles bntCalculate.Click
    Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, dt As New DataTable, ts As DateTime
    dt.Columns.Add("Bottle", Type.GetType("System.Double"))
    dt.Columns.Add("Depth", Type.GetType("System.Double"))
    dt.Columns.Add("Time", Type.GetType("System.String"))
    dt.Columns.Add("Intervals", Type.GetType("System.Double"))
    For j = 1 To (cmbBottles.SelectedIndex + 1)
        Dim jrow As DataRow
        jrow = dt.NewRow
        jrow("Bottle") = j
        dt.Rows.Add(jrow)
        For k = 1 To (cmbBottles.SelectedIndex + 1)
            Dim krow As DataRow
            krow = jrow
            krow("Depth") = k
            For l = 1 To (cmbBottles.SelectedIndex + 1)
                Dim lrow As DataRow
                lrow = jrow
                lrow("Intervals") = l
                ts = DateTimePicker1.Value
                If Double.TryParse(tbAccTime.Text, acc) Then
                    lrow("Time") = ts.ToString(myFormat)
                    ts = ts.AddMinutes(acc).ToString(myFormat)
                End If
            Next
        Next
    Next
    DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
```

I did try and d the following:

```
Public Class Form1
  Friend acc As double = tbAccTime

Private Sub bntcalculate_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles bntCalculate.Cl

  Dim ts As DateTime
  ts = DateTimePicker1.Value
  lrow("Time") = ts.ToString(myFormat)
  ts.addminutes(acc).ToString(myFormat)
```

This adding minutes can change at any time plus its part of a larger calculation

**EDIT** Problem fixed!

```
 Private Sub bntcalculate_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles bntCalculate.Click
    Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, dt As New DataTable, ts As DateTime
    dt.Columns.Add("Bottle", Type.GetType("System.Double"))
    dt.Columns.Add("Depth", Type.GetType("System.Double"))
    dt.Columns.Add("Time", Type.GetType("System.String"))
    dt.Columns.Add("Intervals", Type.GetType("System.Double"))
    ts = DateTimePicker1.Value
    If Double.TryParse(tbAccTime.Text, acc) Then
        ts = ts.AddMinutes(acc).ToString(myFormat)
    End If
    For j = 1 To (cmbBottles.SelectedIndex + 1)
        Dim jrow As DataRow
        jrow = dt.NewRow
        jrow("Bottle") = j
        dt.Rows.Add(jrow)
        jrow("Time") = ts.ToString(myFormat)
```

Regards

Daniel

Comment: You should move all the logic into a separate method (e.g. `AddMinutesAndFormat(ByVal specifiedDateTime as DateTime, ByVal minutesToAdd as Double, ByVal outputFormat as String)`) that you can call from within `bntcalculate_Click`; this will separate the concerns of the UI and the business logic.

Comment: Please put `Option Strict On` at the top of your code file, or enable it in the project's properties.  This line is problematic:  `ts = ts.AddMinutes(acc).ToString(myFormat)`  ts is a `DateTime` and you are assigning a string to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting the value of your double variable to the whole TextBox, not to its value.

But most important, is the fact that [`AddMinutes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.addminutes%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) returns the new date. It doesn't change the data from which you call the method.
So you need to read back the result of the calculation and assign the value to a new datetime variable or to the same input variable.

```
Friend acc As Double

Private Sub bntcalculate_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles bntCalculate.Cl

   Dim ts = DateTimePicker1.Value
   if Double.TryParse(tbAccTime.Text, acc) Then
       ts = ts.AddMinutes(acc)
       lrow("Time") = ts.ToString(myFormat)
   End If
End Sub
```

Notice also, that if you are not sure what your end user types in the TextBox, you need to use TryParse the input because this will remove the possibility of an exception because the string is not in the correct format for a double value.

**EDIT** To fix the problem of the field time that doesn't increment you need to move the line

```
ts = DateTimePicker1.Value
```

outside the loops.

```
ts = DateTimePicker1.Value
For j = 1 To (cmbBottles.SelectedIndex + 1)
    ....
    For k = 1 To (cmbBottles.SelectedIndex + 1)
        ...
        For l = 1 To (cmbBottles.SelectedIndex + 1)
            ...
              ' increment the ts and use its value for the time field
              ts = ts.AddMinutes(acc)
              lrow("Time") = ts.ToString(myFormat)
        Next
    Next
Next
```

Comment: I have tried this nothing happened.. also thanks for pointing out the variable wont change so ill have to define a new one

Comment: What is lrow("Time")? How is declared?. If you put a breakpoint on the entry of this code and run the debugger you should be able to see the value of ts changing to the new time. But after that it depends on the lrow variable.

Comment: I have added the full button in my question, im currently working out each part bit by bit hence for repeated coding.

Comment: You need to remove the assignement to the ts variable from the DateTimePicker value inside the loop. Set it outside the loop and let the ts variable increment by reassigning the result of AddMinutes

Comment: I have moved it now and it has added the minutes. Only problem is that is now using all the loops for increment. I have moved this now to the top of all the loops to stop this but i need it to do it once on the first row which is not doing it only doing it to the row after?

Comment: I have now moved to and sorted what i needed to do. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: ts is a DateTime, but the code is assigning a string to it:  `ts = ts.AddMinutes(acc).ToString(myFormat)`  This code will fail with Option Strict On.

Comment: @ChrisDunaway you are right, of course. Fixed now, nice catch